# Google script: take telegram message and write to a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, telegram

I wrote this little script to dump messages log and write to a specific sheet cell

It worked for some time, then all of a sudden decided not to work anymore. I think there's a bug in google script as even after modifying the code several time I still got the same old message dumps on my phone

it ought to dump my message to sheet Outputs, and date and time of message to sheet telegram. Atm nothing is working

```js
var token = "CENSORED"; 
var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token; 
var webAppUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwZD1K7Q0q6yXVgIVdl3w3PKISmTBBH89zKF1BQdkOgyDzJu4s/exec"; 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("CENSORED");

function setWebhook() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl;
  //var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}

function sendMessage(chat_id, text) {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text="+ text;
  //var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}


function doPost(e) {
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var chat_id = contents.message.from.id; 
  var user = contents.message.chat.first_name;
  
  sendMessage(chat_id, answer);
  var answer = "Hi " + user;
  sendMessage(chat_id, answer);
  
  var text = contents.message.text;
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("CENSORED").getSheetByName("telegram").appendRow([new Date(), chat_id, user, text]);

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Outputs");
  var cell =  sheet.getRange("G45");
  cell.setValue(text); // write to cell message log
```

Comment: DON'T use the `script` tag. It offers no information at all. All SO questions are about scripts one way or another. It's no better than adding `program` or `code`.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what exactly is not working? Are you receiving any errors? Have you made any changes to the code? @Joseph

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The deploy url and id in the script were different